# Куда и как прописать php.ini

Tags: php-fpm, redhat

Я собрал php-fpm из исходников. Все это сложилось в папку /usr/local/php/etc/, но там нет php.ini. Вопрос, куда его положит и в каком конфиге прописать путь до него?

Comment: php.ini обычно лежит в /etc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пришел к решению - выполнить phpinfo(). В информации, которую выводит данная конструкция написан путь, где ищутся ini-файлы, в том числе перечислены пути до уже загруженных ini-файлов.